# How to call TypeAdapter.validate_python on a object which its type was passed as a generic TypeVar variable?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, python-typing, pydantic, python-dataclasses

I have the following abstract Service class, which basically receives a T TypeVar via Generic when created and has a method to call DynamoDB and search an item from a table via id and then runs TypeAdapter.validate_python in the DynamoDB item:

```py
    from abc import ABC
    from dataclasses import dataclass
    from typing import Generic, TypeVar
    
    from app.core import DynamoDB
    from app.core.aws.dynamodb import QueryParams
    
    T = TypeVar("T")
    
    
    @dataclass
    class Service(ABC, Generic[T]):
        dynamodb: DynamoDB
        item_type: type
    
        def __init__(self, dynamodb: DynamoDB) -> None:
            """Initializator for abstract service
    
            Args:
                dynamodb (DynamoDB): instance of dynamoDB
            """
            self.dynamodb = dynamodb
            self.item_type = type[T]
    
        async def _get_item(
            self,
            item_table: str,
            item_id_keyname: str,
            item_id_value: str,
        ) -> T | None:
            """Get item T from dynamodb via item id
    
            Args:
                item_table (str): the name of the item table
                item_id_keyname (str): the name of the item id property in the table
                item_id_value (str): the value of the item id property in the table
    
            Returns:
                T | None: the item T with id value, or None if no item found
            """
            return await self.dynamodb.get_item(
                item_table, self.item_type, Key={item_id_keyname: item_id_value}
            )
```

In `dynamodb.get_item`:

```py
from pydantic import TypeAdapter

async def get_item(
        self,
        table_name: str,
        type: type[T],
        **get_params: Unpack[GetParams],
    ) -> Optional[T]:

        type_adapter = TypeAdapter(type)

        async with self.resource() as dynamodb_resource:
            table = await dynamodb_resource.Table(table_name)
            response = await table.get_item(**get_params)
            if "Item" not in response:
                return None
            return type_adapter.validate_python(response["Item"])
```

This abstract Service is instantiated with a Pydantic dataclass as T value:

```py
@dataclass
class Customer:
    customerID: str
    name: str


class CustomerService(Service[Customer]):
    async def get_customer(self, customer_id: str) -> Customer | None:
        return await self._get_item(
            self.dynamodb.table_config.customer_table,
            "customerID",
            customer_id,
        )
```

But then I discovered that I could not call `type_adapter.validate_python` passing an item whose type was defined via T in Generic[T] abstract class:

```
When using `TypeAdapter` with a Pydantic `dataclass`, the use of the `from_attributes`
            argument is not supported.
```

Is there any other way to keep passing the dataclass type as a generic via TypeVar and Generic[T], and still be able to run validate_python?

Comment: Typically I would just use `from pydantic import BaseModel` and use that to define the data structures, but alternatively pydantic also exposes an equivalent for dataclasses. I would try switching to the other kind of dataclass, or alternatively using BaseModel - you can still validate the response with this but it's more mainstream pydantic and has more features

Comment: But even if I change the class to use pydantic.BaseModel or pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass, how can I convert the response["Item"] to the model T?

Comment: If response["Item"] is a dict structure, just use the .model_validate(...) method of the pydantic model